# Execution failed for task ':qr_code_scanner:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, build.gradle

I installed everything I needed following the instructions in https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows. I believe that there is an error in the code, please tell me how to fix it?

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here is the solution:** Change the version of **qr_code_scanner** in **pubsec.yaml** to **1.0.0**!

Answer (score 3):

try update kotlin_version to 1.7.10

and update com.android.tools.build:gradle to last varsion

then

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 0):

try update **qr_code_scanner**  build file ,

```
targetSdkVersion 33,
compileSdkVersion 33,
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).